# Perl modules not taken from the custom lib path

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have installed Perl into a custom directory ang set export_path. now `which perl` shows the custom path and `Perl -V` shows the details of custom path and @INC shows like custompath/lib/5.8.9 etc.

The issue is, when I run the perl script that contain perl modules like DBI, I get error like

```
> Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
> /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
> /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
> /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
> /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
> /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .)
```

Why it is not showing the **@INC** as custom path and why it is throwing error?

Comment: What's the first line of your script? If it says `#!/usr/bin/perl`, there's your problem. You need to use the new Perl's path.

Comment: okay. Thank you. when I run the script as perl script.pl, it was working. Now ./script.pl is also working.

Comment: Is `Perl -V` a typo for `perl -V`?

Comment: Run `whereis perl` on commandline and place that path in your file as `#!PATH`

Comment: But `whereis perl` displays  **/usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/perl** and `which perl` displays ../custompath/bin/perl . Why this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using one build of Perl for `perl -V`, and a different build to actually execute your script.

`perl -V` (and `perl script.pl`) is using the first `perl` in your PATH, while `script.pl` uses the `perl` indicated on the script's shebang (`#!`) line.

It's probably simply a question of adjusting the shebang line of your script.